# How to read zip file creation date with php

Tags: php, file, gzip, zip

I'm working on large scale business application where I'm facing the issue of creating (multiple files and directory) download button which creates a zip file of directories and files inside those directories. I want to flush the zip files after 24 hours. I want to read to read the zip file creation date and time with PHP. I don't to want to keep track of the files in database I just want to read the file creation date and time and if it has been 24 hours since creation date then just want to delete that zip file. If you know a better way I'm open to suggestions.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (time() - filemtime("test.zip") > 86400){
unlink("test.zip");
}
```

FYI, 86400 is 60 x 60 x 24.

Comment: Hi, wils thanks. If you think the question is valid please vote up for the question. I'll be thankful.\

Comment: Why not just keep `filemtime("test.zip") > 60*60*24` ? more understandable as well as easy to change